# Syntax error or access violation: 1115 Unknown character set: utf8mb4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am migrating my classes but I am getting this error in laravel.

```
[PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

[PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Go to `config/database.php` and replace these two lines with these

`'charset' => 'utf8',`
            `'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',`

Comment: Okay wait. Let me do it

Comment: Its mainly related to mysql version. Mysql 5.6 and above only support character set utf8mb4

Comment: Thank you, mate. I was struggling with this.

Comment: Glad, I'm able to help!

Comment: Every time i push a site live I find myself back here!

Answer (score 7):

Go to config/database.php and replace these lines. That's it

```
'charset' => 'utf8',  
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed in two ways:

1st - edit your .env file

```
DB_CHARSET=utf8
DB_COLLATION=utf8_unicode_ci
```

2nd - If you don't use env-file just edit config/database.php

```
'charset' => 'utf8',  
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Will work for Lumen/Laravel

Answer (score -2):

Edit your config/database.php file

```
'charset' => 'utf8',  
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

run -> `php artisan config:clear`